# ng2-bootstrap not working in angular2 beta 11

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am using ng2-bootstrap its working fine in angular2 beta 9. today i have updated my angular2 to beta 11 version. now i m facing this issue

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No Directive annotation found on Accordion
browser_adapter.js:76 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No Directive annotation found on AccordionBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:76BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.js:86ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:56(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:193schedulerFn @ async.js:122SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:166SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:115Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:74Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:51Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:124Subject._next @ Subject.js:116Subject.next @ Subject.js:73EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:111NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.js:119NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:65ZoneDelegate.handleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:326Zone.runGuarded @ angular2-polyfills.js:235drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:486ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:425
browser_adapter.js:76 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:76ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:58(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:193schedulerFn @ async.js:122SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:166SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:115Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:74Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:51Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:124Subject._next @ Subject.js:116Subject.next @ Subject.js:73EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:111NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.js:119NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:65ZoneDelegate.handleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:326Zone.runGuarded @ angular2-polyfills.js:235drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:486ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:425
browser_adapter.js:76 Error: Uncaught (in promise): No Directive annotation found on Accordion
    at resolvePromise (angular2-polyfills.js:534)
    at angular2-polyfills.js:511
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (angular2-polyfills.js:322)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.js:44)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (angular2-polyfills.js:321)
    at Zone.run (angular2-polyfills.js:218)
    at angular2-polyfills.js:567
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular2-polyfills.js:355)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:35)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular2-polyfills.js:354)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Do you have working plunk for lower version?

Comment: plnkr is needed. I m facing some configuration prbm.

Comment: Cool @micronyks ng2-bootstrap team has upgrading to beta.11. Now it support upto beta9 only. beta 11 angular2 team make some changes such as removed "@view"

Comment: @View decorator was removed in beta.10.

Comment: yes. please check this https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/pull/305#issuecomment-199642771

Answer (score 0):

Its working ! may be there could be some problem with some components(But I don't know).
**[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/vV3qF2yKGKK71tnoNlCM?p=preview)**

**index.html**

```
...
...

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.11/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.11/Rx.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.11/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.11/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.11/http.dev.js"></script>
...
...
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/pull/305#issuecomment-199642771

Comment: You can also check my plunk uses 11.

Comment: As I told you may be some components are not working only.